# Бледные цвета для Android Toolbar

Tags: android, material-design

Нормально ли использовать бледные цвета для тулбара андроида в соответствии с материал дизайном? Начальство хочет именно такое, однако мой опыт мне подсказывает, что белые тулбары существуют - да, с насыщенными цветами тоже полно, но я ни разу не видел блеклый тулбар ни в одном андроид аппе.

Comment: Вообще, по гайдлайнам материал-дизайна, тулбар должен быть Primary Color, а бледный Primary Color это зрелище так себе, но если начальник хочет, пусть страдает созерцая это

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все нормально, главное как использовать. Например если у вас белый тулбар, и сама активность/фрагмент белый, то будет неудобно. Нужно учитывать что тулбар должен быть заметен, а какого он будет цвета, это я думаю дело десятое. Если  у вас есть дизайн, и по нему белый тулбар сочетается например с каким-нибудь серым фоном активности, то почему-бы и нет. Вот например приложение с белым тулбаром:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46363591/app-with-white-toolbar-and-dark-text) откуда взята картинка, как видите в целом выглядит неплохо и ничего особо критичного нет. И наконец - начальство не любит когда с ним спорят :) Сделайте белый цвет, как вас просят, а потом если и правда плохо получится, то вам скажут на что поменять :)

Comment: Как раз проблема не в том, что белый. Тут то все нормально. Хотят блекло - серый

Comment: @ВладимирФишер, так а в чем тогда вообще проблема?) сделайте серый тулбар и все :)